# How do I get a calculator to account for finite values?

Tags: php, calculator

Right now I have a project calculator for a product we sell in two different widths, 2 feet and 4 feet.  What I want to do is get the project calculator to work within the confines of our material, and make a determination on width.  For example, if someone enters 5 feet wide and 9 feet in length, I want the calculator to output 9 feet of 48 inch material, and 9 feet of 24" material.

How would I go about this?

At current, here is the project calculator:

```
<form method="post" attribute="post" action="calc_estimator.php">
<p>Width in Feet:<br/>
<input type="text" id="width" name="width"></p>
<p>Height in Feet:<br/>
<input type="text" id="height" name="height"></p>
<input type="radio" name="material" id="24" value="24" checked="true"><p>24&quot;</p><br/>
<input type="radio" name="material" id="48" value="48"><p>48&quot;</p><br/>
<button type="submit" name="answer" id="answer" value="answer">Estimate</button>
</form>
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
$width= $_POST['width'];
$height= $_POST['height'];
if($_POST['material'] == 24) {
echo ceil($height / 2) /2 * $width;
}
else($_POST['group1'] == 48) {
echo ceil($height / 4) /4 * $width;
}
?>
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Is there an issue with this code or...?

Comment: @RUJordan No, doesn't seem to be.  I am just looking for help on how to expand the calculator based on the stipulations I mentioned in the question. I thought the stack overflow community might have some folks better than I for determining the proper syntax to create my desired output.